# QML plugin doesn't work with shared dependencies

Tags: plugins, qml

Good day!

I have Qt 4.7.3, simple QML plugin and several boost libraries, used by this plugin.

In MacOs 10.5 & WinXp this plugin can't be loaded if shared boost libraries were used.

In Ubuntu 10.4 all work great with both types of boost libs.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

[Bug report](https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTSDK-1063) created.

Comment: You should post a little bit more information and maybe the Qt .pro file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had the same problem. I wasn´t able to load any .dlls that my app.qml needed.
In fact I couldn´t even get the Qt-example to work.

In the end I got it all working by compiling my libraries as release instead of debug, hope that helps.